# Cylinder orientation representation

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to find an efficient computation and representation for the following problem.

Given a cylinder with height $h$ and radius $r$ with a given position $\mathbf{x} = [x, y, z]$ and $N$ number of points with position $\mathbf{x}_{o, i}$ with $i \in [1,...,N]$, is there an efficient way to compute all orientations (roll $\psi$ and pitch $\phi$, neglecting orientation round the symmetry axis) such that no point $\mathbf{x}_{o, i}$ is within the cylinder and is there an efficient representation for those angles?

Any help or pointers would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Two suggestions. First concentrate on infinite cylinders whose axis is through the origin. Second, grow all points by $r$ and then seek an axis-ray avoiding the union of congruent balls centered on each point.